# gulp plugin that will populate index.html

Tags: gulp

I would like to know how I can populate index.html using a gulp task.

I took this from index.html. I want this

```
<!-- build:js js/vendor/libraries.min.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

to look like this after running a gulp task/script.

```
<!-- build:js js/vendor/libraries.min.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

What plugin do I need? Can you provide a sample gulp.task too?

Answer (score 1):

[gulp-processhtml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-processhtml) is the plugin to go for, but make sure to check out the options in the accompanying [grunt task](https://github.com/dciccale/grunt-processhtml).

Judging from your sample, you want to wire bower dependencies to your HTML file. This can be achieved by using [wiredep](https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep) -- documentation is inside.

For the other comments I see in your code, take a good look at [gulp-useref](https://github.com/jonkemp/gulp-useref)